# multiuserchat addinvitationlisterner not working

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am currently working on group chatting which I cannot receive any notification when someone invite me.
I am using a Service to keep track on the notification and my service class implements invitationlistener.

```
    public void onCreate() {
  //code to execute when the service is first created
    Log.d("Service", "Start myCityMessageService");
    this.receive_manager = MyCityUtils.getReceiveManager();
    this.receive_manager.registerReceivedObserver(this);       
    MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener(MyCityUtils.getChatHandler().getConnection(), this);

}
   @Override
public void invitationReceived(Connection con, final String room, final String inviter, String reason, String pass, Message msg)
{
    Log.i("Invite","Here it is");
    handler.post(new Runnable() {  
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Yes button clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroupChatMessageScreenActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    MultiUserChat.decline(MyCityUtils.getChatHandler().getConnection(), room, inviter, "Busy");
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        @Override  
        public void run() {  
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setMessage(inviter + "invite you to a group chat.\nWant to Join?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();   
        }  
     });  

}
```

What is the incorrect part??
Also, I want to keep track on How many people are in the room and want to have all their name to display. Is there any way that I can do that?

Comment: I know that we cannot have dialog box in service.

Comment: So what can I do to receive invitation??

Comment: Now I get a message from my log

Comment: `03-13 04:01:32.011: I/MyCity_ConcreteReceiveChatManager(1117): I received a message: lcyiu1104@gmail.com You Are So Close To Me
03-13 04:01:32.011: I/MyCity_ConcreteReceiveChatManager(1117): Click here to join: http://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/joinpmuc?r=Cm7obfRFneEsWRMLtYb7ixymKlGKGqEK0StMsRWTUP_nRmOTNQUKn4QyKwrw8p3GqrAYnIcTn4Kkf-CPlbteOobggloKUl2AE3Ueti4bnR9N8ZjdJFrOh5sdcy7FHR7botB6BH33nf1SYhFRPlrBexIMFCS0wr6aqB2TpWPeGAE&si=1
 `